# Windows doesn't stop playing music after bluetooth neackband gets disconnected

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, audio, bluetooth

I have [Oppo enco M31](https://www.oppo.com/in/accessory-headphone-oppo-enco-m31/), and [laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/IN/content/model/NX.GV7SI.003).

Device Details:

```
Device name Lordofcodes
Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.00 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (6.90 GB usable)
Device ID   FF9CF9DC-02A0-477A-888F-3BF6D9AF3334
Product ID  00327-35839-35009-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
```

OS Details:

```
Edition Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎Sun ‎25-‎10-‎2020
OS build    19042.906
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
```

Songs play fine when connected to laptop, but when I disconnect bluetooh headphone PC still continues to play songs. While in my phone, android stops playing instantly.

I use groove music to play songs.
version: 10.20122.1112.0